# Parsing LIFX headers returns wrong protocol number

Tags: elixir

I am trying to parse the LIFX headers as per [their documentation](https://lan.developer.lifx.com/docs/header-description).

Here is the code I have:

```
data = <<36, 0, 0, 52, 33, 235, 176, 178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0>>
<< size :: little-integer-size(16),
   origin :: little-integer-size(2),
   tagged :: size(1),
   addressable :: size(1),
   protocol :: little-integer-size(12),
   rest :: bitstring >> = data
IO.puts protocol
```

This tells me that `protocol` is `1027`, but LIFX's documentation says it should be 1024. I've confirmed by using [LIFX's RubyGem](https://rubygems.org/gems/lifx) that this field's value is 1024.

Why in Elixir am I seeing this value of 1027, rather than 1024?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert at this, but I have a theory that the endianess isn't working the way you would expect when you take 12 bits instead of 16. This solution is just me playing around with the numbers as I found it an interesting problem. There may be a better solution, I haven't looked too deeply in to the erlang implementation yet.

If we ignore all other data, then we have this:

```
data = <<0, 52>>

# data is equal to 0000 0000 0011 0100
#                  oota pppp pppp pppp

<< origin :: little-integer-size(2),
   tagged :: size(1),
   addressable :: size(1),
   protocol :: little-integer-size(12) >> = data

IO.puts protocol     # 1027
IO.puts origin       # 0
IO.puts tagged       # 0
IO.puts addressable  # 0

# doing little-endiain on 12 bits = 0100 0000 0011
#                                   pppp pppp pppp
```

Since this is little-endian, if we swap the two bytes round, we get:

```
data = <<52, 0>>

# data is equal to 0011 0100 0000 0000
#                  oota pppp pppp pppp

<< origin :: integer-size(2),
   tagged :: size(1),
   addressable :: size(1),
   protocol :: integer-size(12) >> = data

IO.puts protocol     # 1024
IO.puts origin       # 0
IO.puts tagged       # 1
IO.puts addressable  # 1
```

So one solution is:

```
data = <<0, 52>>
<< p1 :: integer-size(4),
   p2 :: integer-size(4),
   << origin :: size(2), tagged :: size(1), addressable :: size(1) >>,
   p3 :: integer-size(4) >> = data

IO.inspect p1        # 0
IO.inspect p2        # 0
IO.inspect p3        # 4
<< protocol :: size(12) >> = <<p3 :: size(4), p2 :: size(4), p1 :: size(4)>>
IO.puts protocol     # 1024
IO.puts origin       # 0
IO.puts tagged       # 1
IO.puts addressable  # 1
```

Comment: The order of the `p1`, `p2` and `p3` values is different to what I get. I get `p3 = 4` and `p1 = 0`.

Comment: But yes, this solution does work so I'm going to mark it as the accepted one and move on :) Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, p3 is actually 4. I've updated the answer.